# two columns as foreign key in database

Tags: database, foreign-keys

I have a table users which is having a id as a primary key. Another table which is having a column user_id which acts like a foreign key for the table  users and another column which is other_user_id which is also the id of users table. So is it possible to be both become a foreign key for the same column id in the table users.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible to create a foreign key relationship to more than one column primary key